# Homomorphism of Exterior power into Tensor power

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products, exterior-algebra

Suppose $\lambda (e_i \land e_j) = 1/2 * (e_i \otimes e_j - e_j \otimes e_i)$, with extension by linearity. I am not sure how to prove that $\lambda$ is an injective homomorphism because I am not able to work with the products the way I can with regular module and ring homomorphisms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Lemma:** If $f$ and $g$ are functions with the property that $f \circ g$ is the identity, then $g$ is injective and $f$ is surjective.

We can apply this lemma to this problem, by taking $\pi(v \otimes w) = v \wedge w$ (extended by linearity), and observing that $\pi \circ \lambda$ is the identity.

---

Judging from comments, your problem isn't the injective part, but the homomorphism part. Homomorphisms can be characterized using the first isomorphism theorem:

- Any bilinear function $\varphi: V \times V \to W$ extends uniquely to a linear function $V \otimes V \to W$. (and conversely, all linear functions are of this form)
- Any linear function $\varphi : V \otimes V \to W$ satisfying $\varphi(x \otimes x) = 0$ descends to a unique linear function $\Lambda^2 V \to W$. (and conversely, all linear functions are of this form)

which can be merged into a single condition:

> **Theorem:** For any bilinear function $\varphi : V \times V \to W$ satisfying $\varphi(x,x) = 0$, there is a unique linear function $\Lambda^2 V \to W$ that sends $v \wedge w \mapsto \varphi(v,w)$. Conversely, all linear functions $\Lambda^2 V \to W$ are of this form.

It's easy to check
$$ \varphi(v, w) = \frac{1}{2}\left( v \otimes w - w \otimes v \right) $$
has the needed property to define a homomorphism.

Comment: Just to make sure I am doing this correctly: It's clear that $\phi(v,v) = 0$. Therefore, letting $W = V \otimes V$ gives us our desired result

Comment: @Yunus: Right..

Answer (score 1):

You have $\lambda\colon \bigwedge^2 V\to V\otimes V$. An element of the domain can be written uniquely as
$$
\omega=\sum_{i<j}a_{ij}(e_i\wedge e_j)
$$
Suppose $\lambda(\omega)=0$, so
$$
\lambda(\omega)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i<j}a_{ij}(e_i\otimes e_j-e_j\otimes e_i)=0
$$
Now recall that $\{e_i\otimes e_j: 1\le i\le n,1\le j\le n\}$ is linearly independent in $V\otimes V$.

Comment: How do I show that $\lambda$ is a homomorphism?

Comment: @YunusSyed It is by definition. The $2$-vectors $e_i\wedge e_j$, for $i<j$, form a basis of $\bigwedge^2V$.

Comment: I feel like I'm making the assumption that $\lambda$ is a homomorphism (the second line where you bring the map to the inside of the summation). We have to prove that $\lambda$ is a homomorphism

Comment: @YunusSyed No, you haven't, because you defined $\lambda$ on a basis.